# Java RabbitMQ API setUri vs setting params

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm connecting to a RabbitMQ queue with Java and I'm confused that:

`factory.setUri("amqp://user:pass@url:port/vhost");`

works fine, but with

```
factory.setUsername(USER_NAME);
factory.setPassword(PASSWORD);
factory.setHost(hostsStr);
factory.setPort(PORT);
factory.setVirtualHost(VIRTUAL_HOST);

connection = factory.newConnection();
```

I'm getting

```
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
```

What is the difference between these two options of connection?

Comment: There shouldn't be any unless your parameters don't match the ones in your Uri. It's just a "Convenience method for setting the fields in an AMQP URI: host, port, username, password and virtual host." Maybe you've overlooked a difference in them?

Comment: @zapl I reviewed it some hundred times... Also I made URI from the same variables as I created with separated settings... I'm confused